# Bubble sorting using pointers but I have to use pointers to traverse as well

Tags: c++, pointers, bubble-sort

I have to create a bubble sort program using pointers but instead of using i and j for iterations, I have to use pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
```

using namespace std;

int main() {

```
int size = 6;
int size1 = size;
int arr[] = { 8, 6, 11, 3, 15, 5 };
int* myarr = arr;


int* endptr = myarr + size;
int* endptr2 = myarr + size;



for (myarr; myarr < endptr; myarr++) {
    for (myarr; myarr < endptr2; myarr++){
        if (*myarr > *(myarr + 1)) {
            swap(*myarr, *(myarr + 1));
        }

    }
    endptr2--;
    
    
}
```

}

The first loop is working good but I am not able to iterate the second loop for bubble sort.

Comment: You should have simply copied and pasted those two lines of code *as text*.  Why did you believe it was easier to take pictures and post images?

Comment: Please post a reprodicible code sample that we can look at to help you, an image of two lines of a for loop tells us nothing. Also maybe in your second for loop you should name it myarr2, as you've used the same variable name for both your inner and outer loop.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to think of a pointer little more than an integer used as an address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void bubblesort( int arr[], int N ) {
    if ( N<2 ) return;
    for ( int* endptr = &arr[N-1]; endptr>arr; --endptr ) {
        for ( int* p = arr; p<endptr; ++p ) {
            if ( p[0] > p[1] ) {
                std::swap(p[0],p[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {10,3,8,1,2,3,7,9};
    bubblesort( values.data(), values.size() );
    for ( int value : values )  {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Produces

```
1 2 3 3 7 8 9 10
```

https://godbolt.org/z/56roK56do

Comment: yes, exactly like this, thankyou.

Comment: It might be safer to use sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0])

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes. I took your suggestion and fixed the answer.

Comment: @KennyOstrom `sizeof` to get array size is kindof deprecated since there is `std::size`. It covers cases that work with `sizeof / sizeof first element` and more and when sizeof would produce nonsense results it fails to compile

Comment: even better - the important thing is allowing code changes in one place